# Need Ubuntu 11.10 download link

Tags: 11.10, downloads, downgrade

I've been trying to install oracle 11gR2 in Ubuntu 12.04 and am encountering lots of errors, but this hasn't happened in the case of Ubuntu 11.10. Currently I am trying to download Ubuntu 11.10 but I am unable to find the link. Can you guys please help me?

Comment: -1 sorry, had to down-vote as a search online for '[Ubuntu 11.10](http://www.google.com/search?q=Ubuntu+11.10)' brings up the download page immediately.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it from this link

http://releases.ubuntu.com/oneiric/